# PIC I2C clock related problem

Tags: pic, i2c, frequency, clock, timer

I am trying to make an I2C communication with a device by using PIC18F26K83. I use 8 MHz MCU clock. While trying to set I2C clock these options:

1. Use 8 MHz MCU clock & HFINTOSC for I2CxCLK register.
2. Use 8 MHz MCU clock & timer 2 postscaler output while the timer configs were like below:

---

```
void InitTimer2(){
  T2CLK =0b00000101; //500 kHz
  T2CON.B3=0;
  T2CON.B3=0;
  T2CON.B3=0;     // Timer 2 PostScaler = 1:2 (500/2 = 250 kHz)
  T2CON.B3=0;
  T2CON.B7  = 1;  // Timer 2 is on
}
```

3. 250 kHz MCU clock & Fosc for I2CxClk register.
4. 250 kHz MCU clock & HFINTOSC for I2CxClk register.

And only first option worked. However, I believe all four options above should have worked. So my questions are:

1. Is that a correct way to set timer like above code?
2. When I say I use 8 MHz MCU clock, does that mean Fosc is 8 Mhz?
3. When they say I need to have 1 MHz frequency, should I set clock to 1 MHz or 4 MHz? Because in some sites they mentioned that one operation take 4 clock cycles in PIC. So it made me confused actually.
4. Is the below code a correct way to set the oscillator in PIC?

---

```
void Clk_250kHz (){
  NOSC2_BIT =1;
  NOSC1_BIT=1;      // HFINTOSC
  NOSC0_BIT=0;
  FRQ3_BIT =0;
  FRQ2_BIT=0;       // 1 MHz
  FRQ1_BIT=0;
  NDIV3_BIT =0;
  NDIV2_BIT=0;
  NDIV1_BIT=1;      // Divide 4 = 250 kHz.
  NDIV0_BIT=0;
}
```

Comment: Could you better define "worked." How are you judging whether it worked or not? What I2C frequency are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Worked means I could communicate with a device. I want to achive a frequency between 10 Khz and 100 Khz